# Flutter build error: A problem occurred configuring root project 'bidirectional_scroll_view'

Tags: flutter, mobile, view, build, bidirectional

I am trying to build my project to APK file, but I am stuck with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'bidirectional_scroll_view'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V  

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 910ms


The plugin bidirectional_scroll_view could not be built due to the issue above.
```

The command I had run is this: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`.

If someone would help me I would be glad! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just using an old version of `bidirectional_scroll_view` package.